What are the best RPC nodes to reduce latency?
I need help finding a decent RPC node that I can reliably use, preferably with blockSubscribe notifications or if not logsSubscribe notificationsm. I am currently using C# with websockets and my internet speed is around 700 Mbs. I have been using chain stacks for a little while now ($50 tier) where I subscribe to Pump.fun's program but I receive data about 20 - 40 seconds late which makes it useless. Ideally the delay should be 1 second but as long as it does not go above 4 I will be happy. My code is highly optimized but the notifications I receive come in far too slow with lobsSubscribe and if I try blockSubscribe with chainstacks good luck because I will maybe get 2 messages a second instead of 1,000 which is what I should see. I will attach my current logsSubscribe method bellow but I would really like some suggestions on other RPC nodes I can use with much better latency. My budget is around $200/month max atm so I dont need a private RPC node or anything just something with a somewhat decent latency.
            socketProcessorThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                _webSocket = new WebSocket(WSS_ENDPOINT);
                _webSocket.MessageReceived += (sender, e) => Listener(e);

                _webSocket.Error += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Form1.DebugMessages.Add($"WebSocket Error for subscribeTokenTrade: {e.Exception.Message}");
                };
                _webSocket.Closed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Form1.DebugMessages.Add("WebSocket closed for subscribeTokenTrade.");
                };
                _webSocket.Opened += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Form1.DebugMessages.Add("Connected to WebSocket for subscribeTokenTrade.");

                    string subscriptionMessage = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                    {
                        jsonrpc = "2.0",
                        id = 1,
                        method = "logsSubscribe",
                        @params = new object[]
                        {
                            new
                            {
                                mentions = new[] { PUMP_PROGRAM }
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                commitment = "confirmed"
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    _webSocket.Send(subscriptionMessage);
                };

                _webSocket.Open();
            });
            socketProcessorThread.IsBackground = true;
            socketProcessorThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;


At $200/month or less your best bet is probably Helius. QuickNode is cheaper but somewhat less performant. Triton is the gold standard, but is outside your budget.
From your application, it sounds like you might prefer a Geyser subscription, but that's like 10x your intended budget. However, all the geyser providers will usually give some you some credits to try if you contact their sales teams.

Yea I wanted to start off on the cheaper side before I jump into something high end. In terms of Helius would the $50 Developer package provide somewhat reliable block notifications? Would you happen to have an estimate? Secondly, what would you suggest I try as the next step? Obviously a private node would be the the best but if this turns out well what would be the next step up in terms of performance and reliability? Oh yea also where does Helius host their RPC Nodes at?

Helius is probably your best bet at around the $50 price range, the developer tier is just as reliable as higher tiers, but you do have to go to the $500 tier for enhanced websockets. You'll know if you need them lol. They have servers in all the major regions (NA, EU, SE Asia, etc).
